# Three.JS model viewer feasible in phonegap?

Tags: ios, model, cordova, three.js, viewer

I'm trying to make a very simple 3D model viewer in a phonegap app for use on an iPhone 4. I'm using three.js which is working fine when I make a simple website. The problem is that when I try it out on the phone the 3D object doesn't appear. Simple geometrical shapes like a cube and cylinder will load on the canvas but obj files won't.

I use an objLoader to bring in the .obj file and have all relevant files in the same directory in the app just in case. I think the problem might lie with using webGL on iOS but I'm not really sure.

Thanks very much for your help. If anyone has any suggestions for building a model viewer in phonegap for display in iOS I'd be delighted to hear them.

Comment: Anybody out there have any notions or suggestions? I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

As very few [mobile browsers support WebGL](http://caniuse.com/webgl) at the moment I opted to use the canvas to render the 3D models. I used a simple [web 3D object viewer called JSC3D](http://code.google.com/p/jsc3d/) to create a model viewer in PhoneGap on iOS. It can use webGL but I just went with rendering using the 2D canvas.

I tested my app on an iPhone 4 and the result was that the model took between 2 and 5 seconds to load up and when you go to rotate the object it takes some time to redraw it depending on how complex it is. While not the most satisfactory result it did do the job. I'm going to try it out on a more advanced phone in Android and I'll let you know the result.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try use XDK Intel if you are packaging for iphone but for android use AIDE Phonegap. Make sure you use only `var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();`and avoid using
Anything that has to do with WebGL for its not supported on most devices except BB Playbook and BB 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think IOS render ability is better than Android, some scene renders well in IOS, but not in the Android.

Usually the movile have more render ability, than tha mobile app. I use the firefox to render the three.js obj demo, it works well. But when I use the webview in the app, it renders nothing.

I've make an Android app to render stl models. First when I use the mobile browser to render the scene, it not render the full scene, and when I remove the shadow  effect, it renders. Then I try to use webview with WebGlRenderer or CanvasRenderer, no works. Last I refer to the XWalkView of crosswalk a web engine which can used as an addin of the app, to replace the webview, I also close the shadow effect, I renders well.

You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858878/6521116) for more info.

Here is the render result.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You definitely should not use WebGL renderer of three.js as it's not supported on iOS. Try Canvas or SVG renderer.