# How to add crosswalk webview in my own android library module?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, shared-libraries, crosswalk

I am in the development of an Android library module which has to include Crosswalk Webview. I create the library using Github Sonatype (https://github.com/sonatype/). It works fine without Crosswalk Webview. I tried the following 3 methods to include Crosswalk.

**Method 1:**

- Add Crosswalk Webview library in my library project app gradle
- Error : (Compile error)
- Failed to resolve: org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:18.48.477.13

**Method 2:**

- Add crosswalk aar file in my library project
- Reference link for adding aar file [How to import a .aar file into Android Studio 1.1.0 and use it in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826717/how-to-import-a-aar-file-into-android-studio-1-1-0-and-use-it-in-my-code)
- I have downloaded Crosswalk Webview from 
  https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/stable/18.48.477.13/
- Error: (Compile error)
- Failed to resolve: MyLIBApplication:xwalk_core_library_java:unspecified

**Method 3:**

- Add crosswalk jar file in my library project
- Download Link 
  https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/stable/18.48.477.13/
- Error : This method no compilation error but it give run time error that was 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.xwalk.core.R$string

Note: I tried both jar (ordinary, share mode) files

Comment: Method #2 should work. I've downloaded the `crosswalk-webview-18.48.477.13-arm` zip file and it contains a full AS module. It contains a jar, some resources, and a bunch of .so native libraries that are CPU-dependent (so if you were to integrate this into your library you would be stuck with only the ARM or x86 binaries, or else you would have to create a version of your lib for each architecture. TL;DR: Dont do this man, import via gradle.

Comment: In gradle method I can't build my sample project.

Comment: I just realized there is no gradle tutorial anymore in the official page. Apparently its now much more complex to add XWalk and its done using an npm tool.

Comment: I just found [this](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk.html)

Comment: Above link work was working in ordinary android application but library its now work

Comment: app gradle I added                                                                                          compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:18.48.477.13'                               above sample code was working application and I convert library and import  another application I got error Failed to resolve: org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:18.48.477.13

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I create a new app from the webview to XWalkView to render the three.js stl loader demo, which is not support by the webview no matter WebGlRenderer or CanvasRenderer.
Here is the process how to use the crosswalk module:

Step 1:File->New->Import Module

[image: File->New->Import Module]

step 2 select the module and rename if you need

[image: select the module and rename if you need]

step 3 choose all the option

[image: choose all the option]

here android studio may ask you to update, update it

[image]

step 4 process the module dependency

[image: process the module dependency]
[image]
[image]

After this ,the Gradle Build Running automatically
Here We have finished the crosswalk inport.

step 5 use the XWalkView

add this priviledges to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

add hardware acceleration on to application node of AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

add this to layout file

```
<org.xwalk.core.XWalkView 
 android:id="@+id/xWalkView"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</org.xwalk.core.XWalkView>
```

add this to activity

```
XWalkView mXWalkView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.xWalkView);
mXWalkView.load("http://192.168.1.42/test", null);
```

Here we finished
this is the result I use webview and XWalkView to render three.js STL loader.

webview not support

[image: webview not support]

XWalkView supports well

[image: XWalkView supports well]

Haha it works.

---

Follow is the another old implementation , and you can also refer to this good [post] or [doc](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk_rvw.html)[11](http://diego.org/2016/09/20/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio-updated/).

here is the [source code](https://github.com/punyfeir/TestCrosswalkEmbed2).

Download proper Crosswalk Android webview package and unpackage it from  https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/downloads.html

Copy xwalk_core_library_java.jar from crosswalk libs to app/libs/ in the android studio project, and write click on the file, select the "Adds As Library"

Copy other contents under crosswalk libs to app/src/main/jniLibs/

Make an Android Resource dir res2, and copy files in crosswalk res dir to this dir.

Add this to AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


and add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to application node.to use hardware acceleration which is needed by crosswalk webview
```

add this to layout

```
<org.xwalk.core.XWalkView android:id="@+id/webview"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </org.xwalk.core.XWalkView>
```

add this to Activity

```
XWalkView mXWalkView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mXWalkView.load("http://xxxxxx.com", null);
```

if you want to debug romote add this.

```
XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
```

Comment: Referring process

Comment: @RDY I create a new today, and I refresh my answer.

Comment: https://github.com/punyfeir/TestCrosswalkEmbed2  this link help for me thank you @Kris

Comment: Am I correct in saying this only supports ARM? What if I wanted to support both x86 and ARM? I'm not sure which module I am meant to download and import.

Comment: @RobVoisey no it can support many archicture. Refer to https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Ways-to-use-the-Crosswalk-Project and https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started.html

Comment: @KrisRoofe yup, I knew that Crosswalk itself could but I meant that the answer only went into supporting ARM. I attempted following the documentation to support both in the same APK but could not figure it out; will try posting a new question.

Comment: @RobVoisey I havn't try that. I also have that requirement of multi architecture support in one App. And its my next work. I'll begin it a very few days later. If I've some progress, I'll refresh the answer here and inform you. If you have some progress, share it.  thanks.

Comment: what version jar you used in source code.(github link)?